# Matrix dynamic sizing with ReDim Preserve

Tags: arrays, vba

Please, give a look at the following VBA subroutine:

```
Sub mySub()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim myArray() As Double

    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 5
            ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To i, 1 To j)
            myArray(i, j) = i + j
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

This small example is intended to declare a 2-dimensional array and to dinamically resize it via `ReDim Preserve`: at the end of the loop it should return a 2-dimensional array whose each element is the sum of the row and column indexes.

Nevertheless, this line of code returns an error due to subscript out of range:

```
ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To i, 1 To j)
```

Do I need to `ReDim` the array before using `ReDim Preserve`? Even doing that, the issue is still there.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` and debug highlights `ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To i, 1 To j)`.

Comment: VB(A) arrays count from 0, not from 1, unless the `Option Base 1` is in effect, which is not the default and should not be used.

Comment: If you replace `1` with `0` in my code you get the same issue, regardless of the array starting element.

Comment: ReDim Preserve only works on the **last** dimension of a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Then how is it possible to `ReDim Preserve` a _n_-dimensional array?